# VBA: MailItem.CC Doesn't Seem to be Working

Tags: vba, outlook, office-automation, cc

I've got some code designed to automatically send emails with attachments.  It's been working 100% fine but I am now required to CC people as well.  I thought it should be simple and added the .CC property to my MailItem but for the life of me I just can't get it to work.

I've searched the web and other questions on here but haven't been able to get anything to work.

I tried

```
EmailItem.Recipients.Add (CCStr)
EmailItem.Recipients.Add(CCStr).Type = olCC
```

but that didn't work either.  The code still sends to the email listed by EmailItem.To just fine but the CC just doesn't work.  I've posted my code below, any and all help is greatly appreciated.

```
Dim Cust_Email As String
Dim Email As Outlook.Application
Set Email = New Outlook.Application
Dim EmailItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim CCStr As String

E1: Cust_Email = InputBox("Please enter the email of your desired recipient." & vbCrLf &                 
vbCrLf & "Separate mutliple emails with a semicolon: ( ; )", "Who are we sending to?", " 
[Enter email here]")
    If StrPtr(Cust_Email) = 0 Then
    GoTo Final
    ElseIf Cust_Email = vbNullString Or Cust_Email = "[Enter email here]" Then
    MsgBox "You must enter an email address to forward the quote(s) to.", vbOKOnly, 
"Silly goose."
    GoTo E1
    End If
'
CCStr = InputBox("Please enter the email for any recipients you would like cc'd on these 
emails. (Leave blank if none.)", "Carbon Copy?", "")
    Set EmailItem = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    EmailItem.To = Cust_Email
    EmailItem.CC = CCStr
    EmailItem.Subject = "Title"
    EmailItem.HTMLBody = "Text"
    EmailItem.Attachments.Add (filename & ".pdf")
    EmailItem.Send

Final: End Sub
```

Thank you!

Comment: Where are you assigning a value to `CCStr`?

Comment: Can you see the CC recipients in the message in the Sent Items folder?

Answer (score 0):

In the code you have tried to add two separate recipients to the collection:

```
EmailItem.Recipients.Add (CCStr)
EmailItem.Recipients.Add(CCStr).Type = olCC
```

Each time you call the `Recipients.Add` method a new recipient is added to the collection. You need to use the following approach instead:

```
recipientCC = recipients.Add("Eugene Astafiev")
recipientCC.Type = OlMailRecipientType.olCC;
```

After setting up all recipients for the item don't forget to call the [Recipients.ResolveAll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.Recipients.ResolveAll) method which attempts to resolve all the `Recipient` objects in the `Recipients` collection against the Address Book.

You can read more about that in the [How To: Fill TO,CC and BCC fields in Outlook programmatically](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/08/outlook-fill-recipients-programmatically/) article.